# how convert a string into a multiple lambda function using java

Tags: java, javax

I saw this example

[How to convert a string to a lambda expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207447/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-lambda-)
expression

of how to convert a string into a java function

using this code snippet:

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import javax.script.*;

public class ScriptFunction {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Function<Object,Object> f = (Function<Object,Object>)engine.eval(
        String.format("new java.util.function.Function(%s)", args[0]));
    for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(f.apply(args[i]));
    }
}
```

}

In this example: it's extracting a

```
java.util.function.Function<Object,Object>
```

(in this example it a function that get a one parameter)

my question is:

it is possible to run it and get a multi Function Parameter?

how?
because (java.util.function ) doesn't have this type

Comment: Java has [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) which accepts 2 arguments

Comment: pls edit question adding input sample and expected output. I don't see you are providing any Function implementation at all; keeping aside if multiinput function or not ( not like in the stackoverflow link you provide, which is pretty different and provided function implementations).