# Dynamic Streams in Java

Tags: java, dynamic, java-8, java-stream, getter-setter

I've been playing with dynamic LINQ and I was wondering if it's possible in Java to do something similar. For example if I take this working code:

```
Stream<PoliceShooting> averageAge = peopleShot.stream().filter(t->t.getAge() != null);
```

Is there a way for me to make it dynamic like I could do using dynamic LINQ

```
String dynamicGetter = "t.getAge() != null"
Stream<PoliceShooting> averageAge = peopleShot.stream().filter(t->dynamicGetter);
```

Comment: That `.filter()` already accept a dynamic `Predicate<T>`. What else do you need?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you mean by "dynamic." If you mean having a string that's interpreted as a predicate at runtime, then no it's not easy to do that. But it's possible to compose predicates at runtime from an arbitrary number of existing predicates. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22855465/1441122

Comment: I’m talking about having a string interpreted as a predicate at runtime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a string to a lambda expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207447/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 0):

Relying on Nashorn, as proposed in [How to convert a string to a lambda expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207447/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-lambda-expression), you could define a method to build a `Predicate` from JavaScript code:

```
public Predicate<Object> convertJSToPredicate(String js) throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    return (Predicate<Object>) engine.eval("new java.util.function.Predicate(function(t) " + js + ")");
}
```

and then use it as:

```
String dynamicGetter = "t.getAge() != null";
Stream<PoliceShooting> averageAge = peopleShot.stream()
        .filter(convertJSToPredicate(dynamicGetter));
```

Of course `dynamicGetter` must be JavaScript and not Java code, and can access the passed-in object through variable `t`.

Note that [Nashorn was deprecated in Java 11](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/335). I would assume alternative implementations will come.