# How do I convert a string to a lambda function

Tags: java

I need to make a string I input become a python-style lambda function example:

Input:

```
"x ^ 2 - 2xy + y ^ 2" // I introduce the function
eval (x, y) // Tells what variables to evaluate
2, 4 // x will be worth 2, and will be worth 4
```

Output: `4`

That is, I operate it like this `2 ^ 2 - 2 * 2 * 4 + 4 ^ 2`.
I saw a class in another stackoverflow question, but it doesn't work for me:

Code:

```java
import java.util.function.Function;
import javax.script.*;
public class ScriptFunction {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") Function <Object, Object> f 
        = (Function <Object, Object>) 
          engine.eval(String.format("new java.util.function.Function(%s)",
                                    args[0]));
    for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(f.apply(args[i]));
    }
  }
}
```

Input command:
`java ScriptFunction 'function(x) 3 * x + 1' 17 23 47`.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207447/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-lambda-expression)

Error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts7DL.png)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval(String)" because "<local1>" is null
        at ScriptFunction.main(ScriptFunction.java:10)
```

Does anyone have a class that does that? Or could you tell me how I should do it? I am new to this, thanks for your understanding and help

Postscript: I want to make a string become the

Comment: Paste the errors, not a link to the image of the errors. It looks like your just passing incorrect javascript script.

Comment: @matt I changed it and excuse me but a corrector changed it and put the image there and that's it

Comment: And more than using the same I would like to be able to get a class in java and not in javascript if it could be clear

Comment: I've [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64940049/1108305) the question I think you are asking.  That said, it would be helpful (and more aligned with StackOverflow standards) if you can explain why you're trying to solve this particular problem, including why you're trying to execute a JavaScript function, and why you need a lambda.  As it stands, this question risks running into the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Plus, without a clearly stated goal, people have to guess what you want solved, rather than helping with your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the java Function interface only accepts one argument and one return value, you cannot make it accept two arguments, but you can get your example to work by using valid javascript.

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import javax.script.*;
public class ScriptFunction {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    Function < Object, Object > f = (Function < Object, Object > ) engine.eval(
    "new java.util.function.Function(function(x){return 3*x + 1;})");
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(f.apply(args[i]));
    }
  }
}
```

I didn't use an argument for the function. I just passed the string. When I run it as

> java ScriptFunction.java 1 2 3 4

I get the following output.

> 4.0
> 7.0
> 10.0
> 13.0

Comment: ScriptFunction.java:11: error: variable f is already defined in method main(String[])
                Function < Object, Object > f = (Function < Object, Object > ) engine.eval(
                                            ^
Note: ScriptFunction.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, but what I'm trying to find, I don't know if it exists, is a class already created, or a library that does the same as the anonymous lambda function of python but in java

Comment: If you want your lambda to handle more arguments, write your own functional interface.  It would only be about 3 lines of code.

Comment: @WJS True, though Java already has the [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) class which does exactly that.

Comment: @GJTIYK I've edited it to include the complete code that I used, because it compiles and runs fine for me. It sounds like you added the code I used, and not replace the code you used.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear exactly what problem you're trying to solve and why.  Knowing this will help tailor a solution; e.g. would it be better to have a lambda function vs. a method on a class; do you truly want to execute JavaScript; etc..

That being said, I'm going to answer what the question appears to be asking: returning a Java functional type that executes a given JavaScript function on a set of arguments.

```java
import javax.script.*;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public class ScriptRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String script = "Math.pow(x, 2) - 2 * x * y + Math.pow(y, 2)";
        BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Double> eval = new ScriptRunner().asBiFunction(script, Double.class);
        System.out.println(eval.apply(2, 4)); // -10
    }

    public <X, Y, R> BiFunction<X, Y, R> asBiFunction(String javaScriptCode, Class<R> returnType) {
        return (x, y) -> returnType.cast(eval(code, x, y));
    }

    private Object eval(String javaScriptCode, Object x, Object y) {
        Bindings bindings = new SimpleBindings();
        bindings.put("x", x);
        bindings.put("y", y);
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        try {
            return engine.eval(code, bindings);
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The crux of this class is `asBiFunction`, which returns a [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) that takes in two arguments and returns the resulting computation.  The bi-function delegates to the `eval` method, which binds the two arguments to the "x" & "y" Javascript variables, and executes the code with that binding using the [deprecated](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/335) Nashorn JavaScript engine.

The input script in this example has been rewritten to be the equivalent valid JavaScript code.